# Angular method just working with 1 ms timeout

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

Hello guys I want to understand something. I know that it's a bit async but how can a timeout of 1 ms make a difference there. I use it as a solution now but I think that's not best practice.

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.startDate.setFullYear(this.startDate.getFullYear() - 18);

    this.buildForm();

    this.user = this.userService.getProfile().pipe(
      tap(user => this.editForm.patchValue(user))
    );

    i18nIsoCountries.registerLocale(require("i18n-iso-countries/langs/en.json"));
    i18nIsoCountries.registerLocale(require("i18n-iso-countries/langs/de.json"));

    this.currentLanguage = this.translateService.currentLang;
    countryList = i18nIsoCountries.getNames(this.currentLanguage);

    this._adapter.setLocale(this.translateService.currentLang);

    setTimeout(a => {
      this.checkCountries();
    }, 1, []);
  }
```

So the `getProfile()` is a request to the server. The values get patched into the form and this works fine as async solution. Like you can see I use i18n with a dependency and call the method `checkCountries()`.

```js
  checkCountries() { // this method checks the values that come from the database as isoCode and changes them to the whole country depending on currentLanguage
    this.countries = [];
    for (let key in countryList) {
      var countryName: string = countryList[key];
      var isoValue: string = key;
      var isoLowerValue: string = key.toLowerCase();
      if (this.country[0] == isoValue) { // country [0] has the same value as editForm.get('country')
        this.country[1] = countryName;
        this.editForm.get('country').patchValue(countryName);
      }

      this.countries.push({ name: countryName, iso: isoValue, flagId: isoLowerValue })
    }
  }
```

My values get saved as isoCodes into the database and I want to show them in the current selected language as full-text name and that's the reason of the `checkCountries()` method. If I don't use `setTimeout()` it does not work for the formField. It does not get patched. Normal HTML lines that I display with `this.country[1]` work. I has something to do with async I guess but how can 1 ms can make such difference?

My notebook is very strong. Can it be that the 1 ms won't be enough for other computers and that it won't work for them?

Comment: Just a question – what happens if you put no value at all for the setTimeout time? So not even 1 but just `setTimeout(a => { this.checkCountries() });`. I have a feeling this will work too. Doing this ensures that the function is called at the next event loop, which for some Angular operations is a good idea (not doing so can cause 'value was changed after it was checked' errors).

Comment: @MichaelBeeson you are right. I've tested it like you said and it works as well. I just could see it changing at my normal view so from US to USA for example but instantly. You only see something changed.

Comment: check this you will learn some things about how js works https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0

Comment: Hahaha @Xesenix I was going to link to the very same video